# How to create two arrays with different values in them from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
jobHistoryJsonLst = [{
  "uuid" : "bGd_AAABNaMAAAFQHvY0UyTa",
  "startDate" : "2015-10-01 15:22:21",
  "endDate" : "2015-10-01 15:22:24",
  "executionTime" : "0:0:2.951"
}, {
  "uuid" : "lat_AAABqh4AAAFPQ8k0U_qu",
  "startDate" : "2015-09-23 10:50:02",
  "endDate" : "2015-09-23 10:50:06",
  "executionTime" : "0:0:3.284"
}]
```

I would like to create two different arrays from the above JSON object. One should contain all the startDate data and the other should contains all the executionTime data.

**Expected Output:**

```
startDateArr = ['2015-10-01 15:22:21', '2015-09-23 10:50:02']
execTimeArr = ['0:0:2.951', '0:0:3.284']
```

Comment: map() or use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use map() which means processing it twice or one loop with forEach and push it to the array yourself.

```
jobHistoryJsonLst = [{
  "uuid" : "bGd_AAABNaMAAAFQHvY0UyTa",
  "startDate" : "2015-10-01 15:22:21",
  "endDate" : "2015-10-01 15:22:24",
  "executionTime" : "0:0:2.951"
}, {
  "uuid" : "lat_AAABqh4AAAFPQ8k0U_qu",
  "startDate" : "2015-09-23 10:50:02",
  "endDate" : "2015-09-23 10:50:06",
  "executionTime" : "0:0:3.284"
}];

var start = jobHistoryJsonLst.map( function (obj) { return obj.startDate; } );
var end = jobHistoryJsonLst.map( function (obj) { return obj.endDate; } );

//or

var start = [], 
end = [];
jobHistoryJsonLst.forEach( function(obj) { 
    start.push(obj.startDate); 
    end.push(obj.endDate); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or simple loop, like this

```js
var jobHistoryJsonLst = [{
  "uuid" : "bGd_AAABNaMAAAFQHvY0UyTa",
  "startDate" : "2015-10-01 15:22:21",
  "endDate" : "2015-10-01 15:22:24",
  "executionTime" : "0:0:2.951"
}, {
  "uuid" : "lat_AAABqh4AAAFPQ8k0U_qu",
  "startDate" : "2015-09-23 10:50:02",
  "endDate" : "2015-09-23 10:50:06",
  "executionTime" : "0:0:3.284"
}];

var dates = [], 
    times = [], 
    len = jobHistoryJsonLst.length, i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  dates.push(jobHistoryJsonLst[i].endDate);
  times.push(jobHistoryJsonLst[i].executionTime);
}

console.log(dates, times);

// or with .map 

var dates = jobHistoryJsonLst.map(function (el) {
  return el.endDate;
});

var times = jobHistoryJsonLst.map(function (el) {
  return el.executionTime;
})

console.log(dates, times);
```